# WiX - How to copy a dll from one folder to bin folder via wxs

Tags: wix, wix-extension

I have my dll `External.dll` in my ExternLiby folder `$/ExternLib/External.dll`
during installation I want the above dll to be copied to my bin folder.Please note that I dont want to add reference( and copylocal) to this dll through project .My requirement is to copy my external.dll  to my bin folder during msi installation.

here is what I tried by adding following to my  wxs installer file.

```
<Component Id="MY_EXTDLLFILES" Guid="GUIDGOES-HERE-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" DiskId="1" Win64="yes">
  <Condition>"$(var.CKConfig)" = "DEPLOY" OR DEPLOY_DLL = 1</Condition>
  <File Id="MYPROJ.DLLBBIN" Source="$(ExternalLibDll)\ExternalLib.dll" Destination="$($(var.DROPDIR)\bin)"/>
</Component>
```

All I am trying here is during installation I need my installer to pick externallib.dll from $/ExternLib/External.dll  and copy dll to bin folder.how can I do this through my wxs file

Comment: general recommendation: don't share your real GUID

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CopyFile](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_copyfile.htm) element to copy the existing file in machine or copy the installed file to multiple locations. If you want to copy the existing file in machine, doesn’t use **FileId** attribute.

```
 <CopyFile Id="MYPROJ.DLLBBIN" SourceDirectory="$(ExternalLibDll)" SourceName="ExternalLib.dll" DestinationDirectory="$(var.DROPDIR)\bin" />
```